# Is it possible to play 2 different avplayers with the different videos?

Tags: ios, video, avassetreader

Now I'm going to make an video app.

1) In a screen(UIview), is it possible to play 2 independent avplayers?

So for example, in the left panel, one avplayer plays one video file, and in the right panel, the other avplayer plays the other video.

I made 2 avplayers with their own video asset, but then there is an error. i.e. when a video ends up, then the other video also stops...

Please help me.

2) I'm going to extract some video frames to image files using the AVAssetReader.

At first, once I successed, but at the next time I tried to do so, then I can't read any frame.

Some people said AVFoundation is , so in such  my cases, there can be inconviniences...

Is this right?

In an app, can I use the AVAssetReader object twice?

If anyone knows, please help me...
Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you stop one video than remove did finish notification and check that video's object also release and set it to nil.
I think that working fine on two video playing.